# Flutter Web, Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem at Object.throw_ [as throw]

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I have tried to build a flutter web page with firebase auth and firebase firestore. I faced an issue where I was not able login "being blocked by CORS request" after deploying to firebase hosting. I read up online and did a flutter upgrade at flutter channel master, afterwards even running "flutter run -d chrome" is  giving me an error for unsupported error. I heard this can be caused by dart:io imports but I have not changed any of my pubspec.yaml dependencies from before the

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  firebase_auth:
  firebase_auth_web:
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.2
  csv: ^4.0.3
  path_provider: ^1.4.4
  flutter_email_sender: ^2.2.0
  intl: ^0.15.7
  url_launcher: ^5.1.4
  url_launcher_web: ^0.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

The repo is here: https://github.com/lewlian/Attendy

Comment: Hi @Sean ! Could you please add the error that you are facing?

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question.

Comment: There is an [open GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36126) that was related to your error. Could you check if this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

The [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36126) related to your error is still open. There are still on going discussions.

One workaround is to use the [universal_platform](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_platform), as suggested in this comment:

> Current workaround till native dart gives a platform detection feature
> for web
>
> Use Flutter package [universal_platform](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_platform)
>
> ```
> //This will explode on Web
> bool isIos = Platform.isIOS;
>
> //This will not :)
> bool isIos = UniversalPlatform.isIOS;
> bool isWeb = UniversalPlatform.isWeb;
> ```